# How to use onSaveInstanceState to remember image uploaded by user

Tags: android

in my app I let the user to upload an image from his/her phone. When the user closes the app and then open it again I want the image to be still there, but it doesn't work. So far my code is:

```
private static int SELECT_PICTURE = 0;

ImageView imgImage;
Button btnUploadImage;

String filePath;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        filePath = savedInstanceState.getString("FILE_PATH");
        imgImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
    }

    btnUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadImage);
    imgImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgImage);

    btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    selectImage();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getPath(data.getData());

        imgImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

private Bitmap getPath(Uri uri) {

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

    return bitmap;
}

private void selectImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

   outState.putString("FILE_PATH", filePath);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.getString("FILE_PATH");


    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Can you help me with the code? I think the problem is in the onCreate method, but I don't know how to change the code. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RestoreInstanceState could be used when user rotate screen, or change languaje (that force Activity to destroy and be recreated once).

If the user close the app, that does not work, for that reason you could use Shared Preferences, or save information in another place.

This is how you can use the Shared Preferences:

For save some key:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.String("ImagePath", yourImagePathToSave);
editor.commit()
```

And to get again:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String imagePathSaved = sharedPref.getString("ImagePath", null); //null represents the default value.
```

[Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I use Shared Preferences in onPause and onResume methods? But there is error caused by getActivity().

Comment: well you should use the save after you get your file path, and then in the onCreate you should use the get method (but you can use the get when you need)

Comment: Great, I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`getString` returns a `String` variable and you need to assign this to your field

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    filePath  = savedInstanceState.getString("FILE_PATH");


    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

but this is only for configuration changes (like rotating your screen).

If you want the filepath to be remembered when your app is "closed" i.e. te user quits out and swipes it from the recent lists. Then you need to save the file path to memory with SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

in the situation of closing and reopening app you can't use on `onSaveInstanceState`. you can save the pictures path in the `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve it and load image in the `ImageView` in your onCreate method

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
context.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String imagePath = sharedPreferences.getString("image","");
if(!imagePath.isEmpty()){
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
     imgImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```